# Modal view with Web view makes an app crash in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have been developing in Objective-C for two months, so I am quite new to this language and iOS environment. I am updating to iOS7 an app that is working fine for iOS6.

I am getting the next error when a modal view with a web view inside is presented, only in iOS7 and this is working in iOS6. There is a URL request inside but I cannot find what is causing the error.

```
'-[__NSMallocBlock__ absoluteURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16e8b020'
```

This is the viewWillAppear method on the modal view controller:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (!self.webView.request) {
        //THE NEXT LINE THROWS THE ERROR
        NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:self.initialURL];
        [self.webView loadRequest:req];
    }
}
```

Maybe I am doing something silly but really now I do not know where to look at.

If anyone has experienced something like that before, I will appreciate some help. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSURL *initialURL;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)initialURL
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _initialURL = initialURL;

        _webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
        _webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        _webView.opaque = NO;
        _webView.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:_webView];

        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Method call:

```
self.modalWebViewController = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
```

Comment: what is self.initialURL, NSString or NSURL

Comment: What is the data type of `self.initialURL`?

Comment: self.initialURL is type of NSURL

Comment: Can we see the code where `self.initialURL` is initialized/set?

Comment: Try NSString *urlAddress = @"YOURURL";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
...

Comment: how do you determine the value in the debugger? Try setting ab breakpoint on the if-line and then type `po self.initialURL` in the debugger and tell us what the result is verbatim.

Comment: Typing po self.initialURL I'm getting the next results while running in two devices with different iOS versions:
iOS7 `colorMatrix.inputColorMatrix`
iOS6 `file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/XXXXXXXX/Documents/help/how_do_i_connect.html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that iOS calls `absoluteURL` on the `self.initialURL` object passed to the `initWithURL:` method. However, the object receiving this message is an `NSMallocBlock`, so there seems to be something wrong. I assume that your `self.initialURL` object should be of type `NSURL`. If so, this would indicate a memory management problem causing the pointer of `self.initalURL` to point to somewhere else in memory (not to the object you want it to point to).

You could try to run your app with NSZombiesEnabled which prevents any objects from being actually deallocated and instead warns you if a deleted object is still accessed.
You can activate NSZombies in the scheme to run your app (click on the name of your app in Xcode's toolbar on the upper right and choose "Edit Scheme..." from the pop-up menu). In the run-configuration in the "Diagnostics" tab there is a checkbox for activating Zombie objects.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try that.

Comment: This didn't work, this made the self.initialURL variable NULL

Comment: what do you mean it "made it NULL"? Are you sure you just activated that checkbox and ran it again?

Comment: Running the app with this option activated on iOS 7 gives me a null self.initialURL variable, while running it in iOS6 works fine.

Comment: how did you check this?

Comment: but the fact that activating NSZombie changed the behavior of your  code at all is another sign  that your memory is somehow corrupt

Comment: Yes, definitely. I checked that both using lldb and the debug view for variable values. And I could see that everytime I run it I get a completely random value in that variable, and with different types. I'm wondering why this is working in iOS6 and not in 7. Do you know of any change in iOS7 about memory management that could be related and I don't have in my mind?

Comment: No, I'm not aware of any of those changes. Did you do both runs on the simulator? Or did you maybe use two different devices? There is likely a difference in the memory management implementation for the new 64bit processor of the iPhone. Or could it be that you use different versions of your own code with something like `#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 70000` which leads to two different versions of you code and the iOS 7 version has a memory bug?

Comment: I'm using two devices. I'm not doing different code for different versions.
Anyway, I put a watchpoint at this variable while debugging and I saw that in iOS7 is being modified by some tiny_free_list_add_ptr while this does not happen in iOS6.
I wasn't able to find too much information about this tiny_free_list_add_ptr

Comment: The property is defined like this: `@property (copy, nonatomic) NSURL *initialURL;`